# How can I pass a parameter to the wanted function when using Perl's File::Find?

Tags: perl, file-find

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I pass parameters to the File::Find subroutine that processes each file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056649/how-do-i-pass-parameters-to-the-filefind-subroutine-that-processes-each-file)

One can use Perl's [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File::Find) module like this:

```
find( \&wanted, @directories);
```

How can we add a parameter to the `wanted` function?

For example, I want to traverse the files in `/tmp` extracting some information from each file and the result should be stored to a different directory. The output dir should be given as a parameter.

Comment: Please describe more specifically what you are trying to do and I will update my answer.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056649/how-do-i-pass-parameters-to-the-filefind-subroutine-that-processes-each-file

Comment: UPDATE:
I like [File::Find::Wanted](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Find-Wanted/Wanted.pm) better than File::Find. However, brian's module is probably closer to what you really want.

Comment: @ Sinan Ünür your remark 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056649/how-do-i-pass-parameters-to-the-filefind-subroutine-that-processes-each-file

solved the my question. if you post it as an answer i will  marked as accepted

Comment: @ilang7 In that case, I vote to close your question as "exact duplicate".

Comment: @Sinan Ünür  you are right, it is duplicate , shame on me

Comment: @ilang7 No need for any shame on anyone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You use a closure:

```
use File::Copy;

my $outdir= "/home/me/saved_from_tmp";
find( sub { copy_to( $outdir, $_); }, '/tmp');

sub copy_to
  { my( $destination_dir, $file)= @_;
    copy $file, "$destination_dir/$file" 
      or die "could not copy '$file' to '$destination_dir/$file': $!";
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create any sort of code reference you like. You don't have to use a reference to a named subroutine. For many examples of how to do this, see my [File::Find::Closures](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Find-Closures/lib/Closures.pm) module. I created that module to answer precisely this question.

Answer (score 3):

[File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File::Find#The_wanted_function)'s contract specifies what information is passed to `&wanted`.

> The wanted function takes no arguments but rather does its work through a collection of variables.
>
> - `$File::Find::dir` is the current directory name,
> - `$_` is the current filename within that directory
> - `$File::Find::name` is the complete pathname to the file.

If there is extra information you want to make available in the callback, you can [create a sub reference that calls your wanted sub with the desired parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056649/how-do-i-pass-parameters-to-the-filefind-subroutine-that-processes-each-file/2056699#2056699).

Comment: Thanks, 
I'm Aware of this option, but i want to know if there is some hack to pass parameter (not using global).